# How to extract the final model data-set from caret subsampling inside of resampling of a random forest model

Tags: r-caret

Following a subsampling inside of resampling procedure, as exemplified here https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html#subsampling-during-resampling my question is simply how to extract the actual data-set resulting from this procedure when the caret method = “rf” and the sampling method is “smote”.

If, for example, method= glm is used then the data can be extracted with model$finalModel$data; if the method = “rpart” the data can be similarly extracted with model$finalModel$call$data.

Using subsampling inside of resampling and the method = rpart the smote data-set can be extrated as follows:

```
library(caret)
library(DMwR)
data("GermanCredit")
set.seed(122)
index1<-createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p=.7, list = FALSE)
training<-GermanCredit[index1, ]
#testing<-GermanCredit[-index1,] 
colnames(training)

metric <- "ROC"
ctrl1<- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  repeats = 5,
  search = "random",
  classProbs = TRUE, # note class probabilities included
  savePredictions = T, #"final"
  returnResamp = "final",
  allowParallel = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  sampling = "smote")

set.seed(1)
mod_fit<-train(Class ~ Age +
                 ForeignWorker + 
                 Property.RealEstate + 
                 Housing.Own + 
                 CreditHistory.Critical, data=training, method="rpart",
                 metric = metric,
                 trControl= ctrl1)


mod_fit # ROC 0.5951215
dat_smote<- mod_fit$finalModel$call$data
table(dat_smote$.outcome)
# Bad Good 
# 630  840 
head(dat_smote)
# Age ForeignWorker Property.RealEstate Housing.Own CreditHistory.Critical .outcome
#  40             1                   0           1                      1     Good
#  29             1                   0           0                      0     Good
#  37             1                   1           0                      1     Good
#  47             1                   0           0                      0     Good
#  53             1                   0           1                      0     Good
#  29             1                   0           1                      0     Good
```

I simply would like to be able to perform the same data-set extraction when the method = "rf". The code might look like this 
dat<- mod_fit$trainingData[mod_fit$trainingData == mod_fit$finalModel$x,]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way to do it is to write a [custom model](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html) that saves the data object in the `fit` module (that's pretty unsatisfying though).

Comment: OK. I appreciate the prompt response and will need to consider a custom model.Thank you